# Changing Variable Parameters in Different Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a two models in rails, a purchase and a piece. Whenever a purchase is created, I want to set the status of the piece associated with that purchase to 3. Here is my code right now:

In my purchase controller:

```
piece = Piece.find(params[:piece_id])
# This works, as when the purchase is created in my view, it passes the piece_id as a hidden field. 

Purchase.create(
  parameter_1 = blah,
  parameter_2 = blah,
  piece_id = piece.id  
)
#This also works

piece.status = 3
```

The last line is the line I am having trouble with. The `piece` seems to be an instance variable, and I cannot change the status of actual object it is representing. How can I access this actual object and change its status?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by  you *cannot change the status*? Is there an error, what kind of error?

Comment: I cant see "piece.save"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `piece.status = 3`, the object in your `piece` local variable acquires the value, but in order to actually persist the change you have to save the object:

```
piece.status = 3
piece.save!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will assing this, will be better if you create a method in your model.

For example:

```
def default_value
  @piece.status = 3 #or @piece = piece.status = 3
  @piece.save! #or piece.save!
end
```

Then, you can call it in the controller with a `before_action`

I think this is a better way because you are interacting with the database and will help you to keep your controllers not to heavy.

Answer (score 0):

In your create method

```
def create
  @purchase = Purchase.new(purchase_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @purchase.save
      @piece = Piece.where(purchase: @purchase)
      @piece.update_attributes(status: 3)
```